# screenshot - missed option "Take a Screenshot of a Selected Area" on right-click on dock

Tags: .desktop, screenshot, gnome-screenshot

In Ubuntu 16.04 there was the option "Take a Screenshot of a Selected Area" by right-click on the screenshot app on the dock.

In Ubuntu 18.04 this option is gone away.

How to restore it?

The `org.gnome.Screenshot.desktop` file contains:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name[en_GB]=Screenshot
    ... other translations
Name=Screenshot
Comment[en_GB]=Save images of your screen or individual windows
    ... other translations
Comment=Save images of your screen or individual windows
Keywords[en_GB]=snapshot;capture;print;screenshot;
    ... other translations
Keywords=snapshot;capture;print;screenshot;
Exec=gnome-screenshot --interactive
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=applets-screenshooter
StartupNotify=true
Categories=GTK;GNOME;Utility;X-GNOME-Utilities;
NotShowIn=KDE;
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=gnome-utils
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=screenshot
# Disable broken actions https://pad.lv/1720262
# Actions=screen-shot;window-shot;area-shot
Actions=screen-shot;
DBusActivatable=true

[Desktop Action screen-shot]
Name[en_GB]=Take a Screenshot of the Whole Screen
    ... other translations
Name=Take a Screenshot of the Whole Screen
Exec=gnome-screenshot

[Desktop Action window-shot]
Name[en_GB]=Take a Screenshot of the Current Window
    ... other translations
Name=Take a Screenshot of the Current Window
Exec=gnome-screenshot -w

[Desktop Action area-shot]
Name=Take a Screenshot of a Selected Area
Exec=gnome-screenshot -a
```

Answer (score 0):

`window-shot` and `area-shot` actions are disabled in the `.desktop` file. Change the

```
Actions=screen-shot;
```

line to

```
Actions=screen-shot;window-shot;area-shot;
```

(or avoid the `window-shot;` part if you only want the "Take a Screenshot of a Selected Area" action).

*P.S.* It is not recommended to directly edit a `.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications/`. Instead copy the file to your `~/.local/share/applications/` directory first and then edit the copied file.

**Note:** Those actions were disabled intentionally due to [a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1720262). It seems the bug is (partially?) fixed now. If it still doesn't work, wait for a proper fix to be released.